# Split one string column to multiple columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, multiple-columns

I have one string column looks like below

*Summary *: Technology  * Time *: June 2021  * Additional Detail *: xxx  etc

I want to split this one column into multiple columns like below but not sure how I can achieve this

Summary           Time                Additional Detail

Technology        June 2021           xxx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use either .str methods or apply a custom function with result_type='expand'  (latter not shown)

Editing after question was clarified:

```
## given that original column is called 'original_col'
## and a regular pattern is followed.
for i, field in enumerate(df.original_col.values[0].split(' ')): 
    # iterates through first 'reference' cell [chunks of field:value pairs]
    current_field = field.split(':')[0] #field name
    current_series = df.original_col.str.split(' ').str[i].str.split(':')[-1]
    df[current_field]= current_series
```

Comment: Hi Jordi, thank you so much. Sorry that I should have clarified my questions, the original column was formatted like *column name*: xxxx *column name2*: xxxx etc